# pandas groupby multilevel header

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I would like to groupby one of the levels of a pandas dataframe whose index and columns are a Multindex. I'd like to do groupby one of the levels of the header but it gives me a key error and I am not sure why.

This dataframe could be used as exemple:

```
arrays = [['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux'],
['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two']]
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))

arrays2 = [['bar','baz','foo','qux'],
       ['one','two','one','two'],
       ['a','b','c','d']]
tuples2 = list(zip(*arrays2))

header = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['h1', 'h2'])
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples2, names=['first', 'second','third'])

df2=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3, 3), index=index[:3], columns=header[:3])
```

If I try to do

```
df2.groupby('h1',axis=1).sum()
```

I get a key error, but with the index works fine.

```
df2.groupby(df2.index.names[0],axis=0).sum()
```

what is the cause and how could I solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `level`

```
df2.groupby(level=['h1'],axis=1).sum()
Out[960]: 
h1                       bar       baz
first second third                    
bar   one    a     -1.077170  0.585508
baz   two    b     -3.426262 -0.193342
foo   one    c      1.079590  0.336535
```

Or just do `sum` here

```
df2.sum(level=['h2'],axis=1)
Out[965]: 
h2                       one       two
first second third                    
bar   one    a      0.028593 -0.520256
baz   two    b     -3.986019  0.366415
foo   one    c      0.548203  0.867922
```

Comment: thanks! is there a reason why is different in the index than in the header ?

Comment: @Nabla I think it is . :-)